# How do I add a required reviewer when people of a given team create a pull request in DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

After hours of googling and search, I can't find how to add a required reviewer when people of a given team create a pull request in DevOps.

Some people will be able to contribute to our repository, but they are external to our company, that's why we want to enforce this control.

Does anyone ever did it?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently, there is no out-of-the-box feature that can fulfill this requirement. If the following answers are helpful, would you please accept one as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to conditionally set the required reviewers according to which team the pull request creator comes from. If so, I think there is no such built-in function currently provided.

[image]

Currently only the filter condition of "based on which files changed" is provided.

You could add this feature request on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a branch policy in Azure DevOps Repos. In ADO, go to project settings and click `Repositories` in the menu in the Repos section of the project settings page. Click the repository you would like to protect with code reviews and then select the `Policies` tab. Next select the git branch needing reviews.

On the bottom of the branch policies page you can select `Automatically included reviewers`. Click the `+` button to add reviewers. When adding the reviewers you can select if these selected reviewers are required or optional. This is actually something of a rule-builder, you can add multiple 'rules' by repeatedly going through click + and add reviewers

There is also some [documentation on branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers) that might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already use this but it doesn't allow me to trigger those reviewers only for one group of users.

Comment: So the requirement is to only enforce a code review when external users push and just allow all pushes/merges from the internal users? If so, checkout the [Bypass branch policies option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#bypass-branch-policies). I have no personal experience with these, but the documenation leaves me the impression you could could simply create a group/role for you internal users and allow them to bypass the branch policy reviewer requirements

Comment: I'd just like two different behaviors, some reviewers triggered for internal users and other reviewers for external users.

Comment: I don't think that requirement can be fulfilled by ADO in a single branch. You could setup a seperate branch for the external devs with it's seperate set of reviewers and allow those reviewers to bypass the branch policies of your internal branches. And then make sure the external devs are not 'Contributors' on your internal branches. Would take quite some effort to setup though.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought I'd do if there is no way no solve my initial issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, this has been work for year

[Azure DevOps: Automatically add different Reviewers based on Pull Request author using Microsoft Power Automate](https://ngothiensinh.medium.com/automatic-add-different-reviewers-based-on-the-creator-of-pull-request-on-azure-devops-using-22c2cdba1e49)

Comment: When making the API call to add reviewers to a PR, can those reviewers be made as Required or will they be considered Optional?

Comment: @TTT why not? when calling API, just set the `isRequired` in the body equal true
[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/create-pull-request-reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: Have you ever tried it with isRequired? I just tried the PUT and even with isRequired set to true it still only made the reviewer optional. It seemed to have no effect at all. (Note, I tried against api 5.1.)